# alternative to openssl_encrypt

Tags: php, openssl, vtiger

I'm using a CRM software called vTiger which uses the function openssl_encrypt. Unfortunately my hosting (Hostgator) doesn't support it on php 5.2.17. They do support it on php 5.3, but I can't use it as vTiger has a lot of deprecated functions.
That was a bit of background so you know where the question is coming from, now the question:

It is possible to replace openssl_encrypt by other function? how could I do that

Thanks in advance. If that's not possible, please let me know.

Comment: I think there must be other extension such as MCrypt which can help you.

Comment: See for http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to mcrypt you could use [phpseclib, a pure PHP AES implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/). eg

```
<?php
include('Crypt/AES.php');

$cipher = new Crypt_AES(CRYPT_AES_MODE_ECB);
$cipher->setKey('abcdefghijklmnopijklmnop');

$size = 10 * 1024;
$plaintext = str_repeat('a', $size);

echo $cipher->decrypt($cipher->encrypt($plaintext));
?>
```